# Application of Fubini's theorem without integrals

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, stochastic-calculus

Suppose
$$
\forall s \in [0,t] : \mathbb{P}\Big( \omega \in \Omega : \text{a property depending on $s$ and $\omega$ does hold}\Big)=1.
$$
Why does Fubini's theorem imply that 
$$
\big(\lambda \vert_{[0,t]} \otimes \mathbb{P}\big)\Big( (s,\omega) \in [0,t] \times \Omega : \text{the same property depending on $s$ and $\omega$ does hold}\Big)=t
$$
?

Answer (score 0):

Let the function
$$
F\colon \left(s,\omega\right)\in [0,t]\times \Omega\mapsto 
\begin{cases}
1&\mbox{ if the property depending on }s \mbox{ and }\omega\mbox{ holds,}\\
0&\mbox{ otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Provided that this function is measurable, one uses Fubini's theorem to get 
$$
\int_{[0,t]\times \Omega}F\left(s,\omega\right)\mathrm d\lambda\left(s\right) \otimes \mathbb P\left(\omega\right)
=\int_{[0,t]}\left(\int_\Omega F\left(s,\omega\right)\mathrm d\lambda\left(s\right)\right)  \mathbb P\left(\omega\right)$$
and concludes noticing that the inner integral is equal to $1$.